# Transition function and orientation-reversing patches on a nonorientable manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, fiber-bundles, characteristic-classes, orientation

Let us consider gluing many patches to obtain **a nonorientable manifold**.

If we have an intersection of 3 patches, the transition functions must be consistent on this intersection, i.e. there is some thing known as a cocycle condition.

Moreover, some of patch changes are now orientation-reversing.

We need to define and specify transition functions and orientation-reversing patches on how they behave in a nonorientable manifold.

I am asking the principle behinds:

> **What are the rules of transition functions and orientation-reversing patches on a nonorientable manifold**:
>
> (1) for complex line bundles? [thus we only require the SO(n) structure and O(n) structure for manifolds. ]
>
> (2) for the spinor? [thus we require the Spin structure and Pin structure for manifolds.]